# Can I make Selenium wait for completion of Xhr requests

Tags: python, selenium, xmlhttprequest

I´m trying to scrape pricing data for each numerous vehicles, for example:
http://www.leasingcar.dk/privatleasing/Citro%C3%ABn-C1/VTi-68-Feel

I´m iterating over the selection boxes "leasingPeriod" and then "annualMileage".

My problem is that by the time the request has returned, I´ve already scraped the data, so I´m retrieving the same price every time. I´ve tried to use an implicit wait but it doesn´t seem to have any effect? I´ve also tried to wait for the completion of ajax calls but to no avail.

My code looks like this:

```
enter code# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest

class DataTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.leasingcar.dk/privatleasing")

    def testData(self):
        driver = self.driver

        vehicleLinksList = []

        vehicleLinks =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.vehicle[data-nice_url]')
        for linkElement in vehicleLinks:
            vehicleLinksList.append(linkElement.get_attribute("data-nice_url"))

        for link in vehicleLinksList:
        fullUrl = ""
        fullUrl = "http://www.leasingcar.dk" + str(link)
        driver.get(fullUrl)

        leasingPeriodElements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id=leasingPeriod]")  #get the select element
        periodsOptions = leasingPeriodElements.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

        mileageElements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id=annualMileage]")  #get the select element
        mileageOptions = mileageElements.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

        periodOptionsList = []
        mileageOptionList = []

            for option in periodsOptions:
                periodOptionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

            for option in mileageOptions: 
                mileageOptionList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

            for optionValue in periodOptionsList:
                print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue
                leasingPeriodElement = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id=leasingPeriod]"))
                leasingPeriodElement.select_by_value(optionValue)

                for mileageValue in mileageOptionList:

                    mileageElement = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id=annualMileage]"))
                    mileageElement.select_by_value(mileageValue)

                    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                    #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ajax_complete,  "Timeout waiting for page to load")

                    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                    price = wait.until(wait_for_visible_element_text_to_contain((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.total-price"), "Kr."))

                    print price.text

                   #driver.refresh()
                   #driver.implicitly_wait(10)

def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


class wait_for_visible_element_text_to_contain(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            elements = EC._find_elements(driver, self.locator)
            for element in elements:
                if self.text in element.text and element.is_displayed():
                    return element
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

def ajax_complete(driver):
    try:
        return 0 == driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
    except WebDriverException:
        pass
```

Is there any way to check whether requests have been completed, or if a value has been refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Frank,

Use an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to determine when the "Leasing Period" changes in the data table. Something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

xpath = "//div[@class='data-last']/span[@class='period']"

for elm in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    if elm.is_displayed():
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            lambda _: elm.text == "48"
        )
```

NOTE: I had to use `find_elements_by_xpath` and check if the elements are displayed because there is a hidden element with that same xpath.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don´t think I´ve made myself clear enough. My problem is when the annual mileage changes from say 15,000 km to 20,000 km and a request for a new price is sent, I scrape the data before the new price has been returned. I need to somehow delay the process until I´m certain page data has been refreshed?

Comment: You would do the same thing for mileage then. When you adjust the select box just wait for the value of the mileage indicator to change by using WebDriverWait.until and looking for the adjusted value.

Selenium is purposeful in not letting you see the backend of the system and what's going on. It's made for user acceptance testing. Users aren't going to know/care that there is an AJAX request happening, just that the values they were looking for have changed.